# SSH ForcedCommand causes connection to close

Tags: ssh, openssh, connection, authorized-keys

I'm SSHing a server (I'm on cygwin using openSSH), and I went into authorized_keys and modified the file as follows:
ssh-rsa [key]
to
command="echo Working" ssh-rsa [key]

Now when I connect to the server I get the output working but then right after that I get "Connection to [server name] closed."

Why does the connection close? Did I do something wrong, or does the server somehow not allow forced commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're *replacing* whatever shell you'd usually start by that command. So it actually behaves exactly as configured: Connect, authenticate, run the `echo` command, and exit.

This is supposed to be used to trigger e.g. automated jobs like backups when using a certain key to authenticate, where the connection is closed after the program call returns.

Comment: So if I wanted to run that command and stay connected after, what part of the command would I change? I wanted to run a startup script and stay connected, the echo Working was just for test purposes.

Comment: @gsingh2011 You could try to run `echo Working ; bash` or `echo Working && bash` to launch a bash shell explicitly. I'm not sure it'll work though.

Comment: echo Working ; bash worked correctly. Learned something new today :)